# Android simple text note app with encryption to SD and plain-text export

Tags: android, note-taking, encryption

I have tried various note taking apps, including some that encrypt the text in storage.

Features I want:

- Needs no more app permissions other than to *read/modify USB storage*.
- Uses industry-standard encryption (e.g. AES256).
- Stores data to phone's USB storage so I can make backup copies to PC.
- Whole database can be exported to plain text (unencrypted).
  Either in-app or using a PC-based program on a copy of the database.
- Supports plain text notes.
- Notes sortable by name.
- Maybe some way of grouping notes (folders or categories or keywords).
- Few or no fancy features.

Comment: Not using such, hence no answer – but according to my [list of notes apps](http://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/office_notes), [CrocodileNote](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=groomiac.crocodilenote) might be a match: only storage perms, AES256, export (as ZIP), supports plain-text, no fancy other stuff. Cannot tell for the remaining points ;)